# how to generate a XML file in php server at run time

Tags: php, xml, phpmyadmin, domparser

I used this following code of stack over flow link when i run that program,server has error on line 24,column 4 .I don't understand this error like that:" mismatch XML tags"please check this. here the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
  <track>
    <path>song1.mp3</path>
    <title>Track 1 - Track Title</title>
  </track>
  <track>
    <path>song2.mp3</path>
    <title>Track 2 - Track Title</title>
  </track>
  <track>
    <path>song3.mp3</path>
    <title>Track 3 - Track Title</title>
  </track>
  <track>
    <path>song4.mp3</path>
    <title>Track 4 - Track Title</title>
  </track>
  <track>
    <path>song5.mp3</path>
    <title>Track 5 - Track Title</title>
  </track>
  <track>
    <path>song6.mp3</path>
    <title>Track 6 - Track Title</title>
  </track>
  <track>
    <path>song7.mp3</path>
    <title>Track 7 - Track Title</title>
  </track>
  <track>
    <path>song8.mp3</path>
    <title>Track 8 - Track Title</title>
  </track>
</xml>
```

I would like to use some PHP code like this:

```
<?php

  // Send the headers
  header('Content-type: text/xml');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Cache-control: private');
  header('Expires: -1');

  echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
  echo '<xml>';

  // echo some dynamically generated content here

  /*
     <track>
        <path>song_path</path>
        <title>track_number - track_title</title>
     </track>
  */

  echo '</xml>';

?>
```

Comment: line 24  error is last </track> of closing tag is mising i correct this error but not desolve to error

Comment: i don't understand  that line of code that how to echo some dynamically generated found.would you tell me what i put in that line.

Comment: @HinaSiddiqui Where are you getting your data from? e.g. database, file on disk, looping directory etc

Comment: I don't think you've described your situation fully. What exactly are you trying to do? are you trying to generate the first file from the 2nd? If so you will definitely needs a lot more code --> looping structures.

Comment: i used data from database MySQL when user login to login page and click on submit button it will display a message through XML string that "tour account successfully creates' through XML tags.

Comment: Please take a look at some other questions and maybe read http://stackoverflow.com/faq. You asked three questions and all of them got down-voted.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure your error comes from using `<xml>` as the entity, look at this working example, hope it helps.

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tracks>
    <track>
         <path>song1.mp3</path>
         <title>Track 1 - Track Title</title>
    </track>
    <track>
         <path>song2.mp3</path>
         <title>Track 2 - Track Title</title>
    </track>
    <track>
         <path>song3.mp3</path>
         <title>Track 3 - Track Title</title>
    </track>
    <track>
         <path>song4.mp3</path>
         <title>Track 4 - Track Title</title>
    </track>
    <track>
         <path>song5.mp3</path>
         <title>Track 5 - Track Title</title>
    </track>
    <track>
         <path>song6.mp3</path>
         <title>Track 6 - Track Title</title>
    </track>
</tracks>';
?>
```

Comment: why you are used in single quote and semi colon at the end of xml

Comment: @HinaSiddiqui I dont understand what you mean.. the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
` has nothing todo with the php part, I used single quotes as it saves escaping the double quote in the xml declaration.